# Want to set value in formula location

Tags: excel, formula

If I have a formula named "top_row" which point to the cells "A1:A90" is there any way to read the definition of the cell?
This is so I can have a sheet with configuration values that would be
[formula1][value1]
[formula2][value2]

There would be different sets of values and not all would have the same entries, hence wanting to list by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just iterate through all the available named ranges in Current Workbook and use the values:

**try this:**

```
Range("A1") = "Name"
Range("B1") = "Reference"

With Range("A1:B1")
.Font.Bold = True
.Font.Underline = True
End With
intCount = 2

For Each namedRange In ThisWorkbook.Names

Range("A" & intCount).Value = namedRange.Name
Range("B" & intCount).Value = namedRange

intCount = intCount + 1
Next
```

Comment: Thanks. I will have to do it slightly differently but your code shows what I need (ThisWorkBook.Names and namedRange.Name). I will post an nswer with my sample code later.